# How to compare two strings in assembly and replace one with another in txt file?

Tags: assembly

I need to write an assembly program, that would search for one string in the data txt file and replace it with the second string. In the result txt file I need to receive the same txt file, but strings have to be replaced. In my written program, everything works until the TextManipulations section and I don't understand what should I do.

```
.MODEL small
.STACK 256
.DATA
    help db "Hello,", 10, 13, "provide arguments like in the example: program.exe data.txt abcd EFG res.txt", 10, 13, "$"
    FileProblem db "Provided file wasn't found.", 10, 13, "Provide arguments like in the example: program.exe data.txt abcd EFG res.txt", 10, 13, "$"
    input db 255 dup(0)
    inputFD dw, ?               
    string1 db 255 dup(0)
    string2 db 255 dup(0)
    output db 255 dup(0)
    outputFD dw, ?              
    buffer db 50000 dup(?)
    tempBuf db 255 dup(?)       
.CODE
Start:
    mov ax, @data
    mov ds, ax

    xor cx, cx
    xor ah, ah
    mov cl, [es:0080h]
    cmp cx, 4
    jbe Helpmsg
    jne SkipHelp

SkipHelp:

    xor di, di
    mov bx, 82h
    mov si, offset input
    call SaveArgument
    mov si, offset string1
    call SaveArgument
    mov si, offset string2
    call SaveArgument
    mov si, offset output
    call SaveArgument

    xor ax, ax
    mov ah, 3Dh
    mov al, 00
    mov dx, offset input
    int 21h
    jc MissingFile
    mov inputFD, ax

    mov ah, 3Fh
    mov bx, inputFD
    mov cx, 200
    mov dx, offset buffer
    int 21h

    mov ah, 3Ch
    mov cx, 0
    mov dx, offset output
    int 21h
    mov outputFD, ax
    
    call TextManipulations
    
    mov ah, 3Eh
    mov bx, outputFD
    int 21h

Final:
    mov ah, 4Ch
    int 21h

Helpmsg:
    mov ah, 09h
    mov dx, offset help
    int 21h
    JMP Final

MissingFile:
    mov ah, 09h
    mov dx, offset FileProblem
    int 21h
    jmp Final


SaveArgument PROC
Begin:
    mov dx, [es:bx]
    inc bx
    cmp dl, 20h
    je StopSpace
    cmp dl, 13
    je StopEnter
    mov byte ptr [si], dl
    inc si
    jmp Begin
StopSpace:
    inc di
    ret
StopEnter:
    cmp di, 3
    jb Helpme
    ret
Helpme:
    mov ah, 09h
    mov dx, offset help
    int 21h
    mov ah, 4Ch
    int 21h
    ret
SaveArgument ENDP


TextManipulations PROC
    mov si, offset buffer
    mov di, offset string1
    xor cx, cx
    push cx

Read:
    mov ah, 3Fh
    mov bx, inputFD
    mov cx, 1
    mov dx, si
    int 21h    

    cmp byte ptr [si], 0
    je Return
    mov al, byte ptr [si]
    mov ah, byte ptr [di]
    cmp al, ah
    je CheckForString
    mov al, 0
    mov ah, 40h
    mov bx, outputFD
    mov dx, offset tempBuf
    mov cx, 1
    int 21h
    mov cx, 1
    mov dx, si
    int 21h
    inc si
    mov di, offset string1
    pop cx
    xor cx, cx
    push cx

    jmp Read

CheckForString:
    pop cx
    inc cx
    inc di
    cmp byte ptr [di], 0
    je PrintString
    push di
    mov di, offset tempBuf
    mov byte ptr [di], al
    pop di
    inc si
    push cx
    jmp Read

PrintString:
    pop cx
    mov ah, 40h
    mov bx, outputFD
    mov cx, 1                           
    mov dx, offset string2
    int 21h
    inc si
    xor cx, cx
    push cx
    jmp Read

Return:
    ret

TextManipulations ENDP


END Start
```

I've tried lots of different ways to compare and change those strings, however every time it is one out of two, it is changing strings but not printing all the symbols or doesn't work completely.

Comment: A2009 Syntax error in expression, line 7 and 11. A2032 Invalid use of registers, line 84.

Comment: Hmmm, `[es:0080h]` is field in `PSP`, total number of characters in parameter area (offset `81h`). My debugger shows `1ah` value in this field = 26 and later program compares this to 4. It looks like number of parameters (4) is compared to length of parameters area.

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**

Ok, I wrote this proc `TextManipulations`. I think it is working. Correct values are in buffer but problem is with this part:

```
Save_to_res_txt:        
    mov ah, 40h
    mov bx, outputFD
    mov cx, 9; filesize                           
    mov dx, offset buffer
    int 21h
```

`filesize` is a number of bytes read from file `data.txt`. After strings manipulation program should write same amount of bytes from buffer using `ah = 40h, int 21h` to file `res.txt`. Debugger shows good values in all registers but after int 21h random characters appear in res.txt `慡硡䙅G扸扢`.

If program writes more than 9 bytes, there are random characters in file res.txt. If less or equal 9 file contains good values (9 out of 12).

**If I change output from file to console `mov bx, 2` program shows correct string.**

I don't know what to do with this so I use standard output to show final result.

---

**First answer**

I checked this in debuger. Yeah, problem is inside `TextManipulations`.

For example `data.txt` contains this characters `aaaxabcdxbbb`.

`buffer = aaaxabcdxbbb`
`string1 = abcd`

First comparison is ok

```
    mov al, byte ptr [si]               ; 61 | 61
    mov ah, byte ptr [di]               ; 61 | 62
    cmp al, ah
```

`CheckForString` moves `di` to next positon in `string1`.
Character is saved to `tmpBuffer` and program jumps to check next characters.

Now we have `a` and `b` so this is mismatch.

`mov ah, 40h` writes 1 character (cx = 1) from `tmpBuffer` to `res.txt`.

And this next part stops my debugger, return to system.

```
    mov cx, 1
    mov dx, si
    int 21h
```

If I change input to `abaxabcdxbbb`, output has only `b` inside. Character is always stored in same place in `tmpBuffer` because `di` is always equal to `offset tempBuf`.

---

**Code:**

```
.MODEL small
.STACK 256
.DATA
    help db "Hello,", 10, 13, "provide arguments like in the example: program.exe data.txt abcd EFG res.txt", 10, 13, "$"
    FileProblem db "Provided file wasn't found.", 10, 13, "Provide arguments like in the example: program.exe data.txt abcd EFG res.txt", 10, 13, "$"
    input db 255 dup(0)
    inputFD dw ?               
    filesize dw 0                   
    string1 db 255 dup(0)
    string2 db 255 dup(0)
    output db 255 dup(0)
    outputFD dw ?              
    buffer db 512 dup(?)
    tempBuf db 255 dup(?) 
      
.CODE
Start:
    mov ax, @data
    mov ds, ax

    xor cx, cx
    xor ah, ah
    mov cl, [es:0080h]
    cmp cx, 4                           ; 4 parameters, 26 characters total, skip Helpmsg
    jbe Helpmsg
    jne SkipHelp

SkipHelp:

    xor di, di                          ; di = 0
    mov bx, 82h                         ; bx = parameter area(81h) + 1 (skip space)
    mov si, offset input                ; save argument in input / data.txt - input file ... offset 00c7
    call SaveArgument                   ; data.txt copied to ds:00c7
    mov si, offset string1              ; save argument in string1 / abcd ... offset 01ca
    call SaveArgument                   ; abcd copied to ds:01ca
    mov si, offset string2              ; save argument in string2 / EFG ... offset 02c9
    call SaveArgument                   ; EFG copied to ds:02c9
    mov si, offset output               ; save argument in output / res.txt - output file ... offset 03c8
    call SaveArgument                   ; res.txt copied to ds:03c8

    xor ax, ax                          
    mov ah, 3Dh                         ; open file
    mov al, 00                          ; read-only
    mov dx, offset input                ; data.txt
    int 21h                     
    jc MissingFile
    mov inputFD, ax                     ; data.txt handle

    mov ah, 3Fh                         ; read from data.txt
    mov bx, inputFD                     ; data.txt handle
    mov cx, 200                         ; read 200 bytes    
    mov dx, offset buffer               ; read here, ds:04c9
    int 21h                             ; return ax = 12 bytes read
                                        ; data.txt = aaaxabcdxbbb
    mov filesize, ax                    ; save file size, we use this later
    
    mov ah, 3Ch                         ; create / open file
    mov cx, 2                           ; read-only
    mov dx, offset output               ; file name "res.txt"
    int 21h
    mov outputFD, ax                    ; res.txt handle
    
    call TextManipulations              
    
    mov ah, 3Eh                         ; close file
    mov bx, outputFD
    int 21h

Final:
    mov ah, 4Ch                         ; bye
    int 21h

Helpmsg:
    mov ah, 09h
    mov dx, offset help
    int 21h
    JMP Final

MissingFile:
    mov ah, 09h
    mov dx, offset FileProblem
    int 21h
    jmp Final


SaveArgument PROC
Begin:
    mov dx, es:[bx]                     ; dx = character from parameter area            
    inc bx                              ; move to next character
    cmp dl, 20h                         ; space separates parameters
    je StopSpace
    cmp dl, 13                          ; we reached end of parameters area
    je StopEnter
    mov byte ptr [si], dl               ; insert character to [si]
    inc si                              ; next position in memory area pointed by si
    jmp Begin                           ; repeat
StopSpace:                              
    inc di                              ; increment number of parameters or count spaces between params ?
    ret                                 ; we are done here
StopEnter:
    cmp di, 3                           ; 3 spaces separates 4 params, if less we have error
    jb Helpme
    ret
Helpme:
    mov ah, 09h
    mov dx, offset help
    int 21h
    mov ah, 4Ch                         ; see You next time
    int 21h
    ret
SaveArgument ENDP

TextManipulations PROC
    mov si, offset buffer               ; buffer = aaaxabcdxbbb, 04c9
    mov di, offset string1              ; string1 = abcd, 01c6
    xor cx, cx                          ; matching letters counter
    mov dx, di                          ; save offset of the first character in string1 

    Read:   
        cmp byte ptr [si], 0            ; end of buffer ?
        je Return                       ; yes, no more characters in buffer, return
    
        Characters_cmp:
            mov al, byte ptr [si]       ; 61 | 61
            mov ah, byte ptr [di]       ; 61 | 62
            cmp al, ah
            je Characters_are_equal
    
        Reset_strings:                  ; characters are diffrent
            cmp dx,di                   ; if first letter in string1 is diffrent from letter in buffer
            jz next_in_buffer           ; take another letter from buffer to avoid infinity loop    
        
            mov di, offset string1      ; else just reset position in string1
            jmp Reset_counter
        
        next_in_buffer:
            inc si      

        Reset_counter:
            xor cx, cx                  ; reset counter
            jmp Characters_cmp

    Characters_are_equal:
        inc cx                          ; increase counter
        inc si                          ; next character in buffer
        inc di                          ; we want to check next character in string1
        cmp byte ptr [di], 0            ; we checked all characters ?
        je ReplaceString                ; yes, we found matching string

        jmp Read

    ReplaceString:
        sub si,cx                           ; move to start of the matching string
        mov bx, offset string2              ; copy this to buffer
        
        Copy_new_string:
            mov al,[bx]
            mov [si],al
            inc si
            inc bx
            loop Copy_new_string
    
    
        Save_to_res_txt:        
            mov ah, 40h
            mov bx, 2             ;[outputFD]
            mov cx, [filesize]    ; 9                           
            mov dx, offset buffer
            int 21h

    Return:
        ret
TextManipulations ENDP
END Start
```